# Monitor Server Logins / SSH Access?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security

I seem to have some suspicious activity happening on my server from time to time.

Aside from changing passwords regularly, I would like to be emailed ( or logged ) each time a user accesses my apache server, either by logging in to the cPanel directly or through SSH access.

Is this possible?

The customer service rep. told me that the most I could so was check the "last login" i.p address.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Configure [logstash](http://logstash.net/) to watch your `auth.log`, searching for new logins and then use the [email output](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/outputs/email) to email you new events that come through.

As for cPanel, just turn it off. Stop using it. It's not worth the inconvenience caused to millions of electrons by its being active on your system.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @EEAA answer, you should lock down SSH - at minimum to requiring the use of passphrases to log in, but ideally locking down access to IP addresses (or if this is not possible requiring a connection over a VPN).

I have not used logstash myself, but another invaluable tool in your arsenal would be fail2ban.  You can configure it to monitor your logfiles in realtime, and email you and optionally ban users.    Like @EEAA I don't use CPANEL and would recommend removing it as it can't improve your security - but if you do need it, configuring fail2ban (or maybe logstash) to look through your apache log files looking for login attempts from CPANEL might be a good idea.   Again - if you need cpanel access, maybe you can configure it to only work across a VPN or from certain hosts.

I would not put any faith in what the customer service tech told you - Using the "last login" is not a good answer to the question.